# Borrowing breaks when I add lifetime parameters

Tags: rust

I am implementing the board game Nine Man's Morris in Rust. I have a `Game` struct which owns a `Board` struct. `Board` stores a `RefCell<HashSet>` of references to a `Position` struct. `Board` and `Game` share lifetime parameters.

```
pub struct Board<'a> {
    pub positions: Vec<Position>,
    pub ids_to_positions: HashMap<String, usize>,
    p1_mills: RefCell<HashSet<(&'a Position, &'a Position, &'a Position)>>,
    p2_mills: RefCell<HashSet<(&'a Position, &'a Position, &'a Position)>>,
    can_mill: Cell<bool>,
}
pub struct Game<'a> {
    pub board: Board<'a>,
    pub player1: Player,
    pub player2: Player,
    current_player_id: i8,
}
```

`Game::game_loop` loops through a set of methods (get input, update the board, etc) until the game has ended. This has been working fine as I've added methods to it.

```
impl<'a> Game<'a> {
    pub fn print(&self) {
        self.board.print();
    }

    pub fn game_loop(&'a mut self) {
        loop {
            self.print();
            self.make_move();
            print!("can_mill: {}", self.board.can_mill());
            self.board.update_mills(self.current_player_id);
            self.switch_player();
        }
    }
    pub fn make_move(&mut self) {}
    pub fn switch_player(&self) {}
}
```

There is a mix of methods with mutable and immutable references to `self`, and 2 calls on `Board`:

```
pub fn can_mill(&self) -> bool {}
pub fn update_mills(&'a self, player_id: i8) {}
```

`update_mill` updates the `p1_mills` and `p2_mills` fields, and `can_mill` references the `can_mill` field.

If I remove the `update_mills` call in `game_loop`, the code compiles. With it, I get

> cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.board` is also borrowed
>   as immutable.

I'm pretty sure this has something to with the explicit lifetime in that method, but in all my reading around I haven't been able to get it to work or understand what isn't working. It's confusing because without I don't get any borrowing errors. I'm also not clear if having the mill sets in `RefCell`s is breaking anything (I can't actually remember why there are in them in the first place to be honest).

I realise this is quite involved but I'd really appreciate some help. I tried to recreate the issue with a simpler example but couldn't sadly.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. If you can reproduce the issue in the [Rust playground](//play.rust-lang.org), that would be great.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, it seems that was the issue in the end, although the compiler message didn't seem to be saying so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my problem is, indeed, an abstracted version of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) I think using the `RefCells` *sort of* got around the issue, but actually really just abstracted the issue away from me.

Got rid of the RefCells, removed the lifetime parameters, and made a little `Mill` struct that stored `usizes` to index the `Position` `Vec` with.

Comment: Some advice for other newcomers like me would be - don't use smart pointer stuff like `RefCell` unless you _really_ know what you are doing with them and properly get lifetime stuff.